# Unable To Start Tomcat 7: NoSuchMethodError getSessionCookieConfig()

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, catalina

I have used Tomcat about two months ago and it started OK. Now I'm getting this message:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1678)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1374)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
```

Please note the following behavior:

- I get this error when I attempt to run catalina.bat. If I run Tomcat via Eclipse, it launches successfully
- I downloaded the same version of Tomcat again and run it immediately without adding any webapps (to simply load the default Tomcat localhost page) but again I get this error.
- As per previous similar questions, I replaced `servlet-api.jar` in apache's `lib` folder, but it has made no difference

I was successfully able to launch `startup.bat` recently and I don't think anything has changed. Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Could you publish the link from where you download the tomcat? Or upload the zipped archive somewhere?

Comment: Is CATALINA_HOME environment variable set your machine? Any chance $CATALINA_HOME/lib or $CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties are part of another tomcat installation?

Comment: CATALINA_HOME is set to `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47`. I downloaded Tomcat v7.0.47 from the Apache website

Comment: The error happens when you start virgin (==unpacked from zipped archive you downloaded and without any application deployed) tomcat using catalina.bat from the fresh installation?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You have the default applications deployed. Please remove all subfolders in webapps as I stated in my answer. The error happens when deploying an application, in your case the docs application contained in tomcat archive you downloaded. It is stated clearly in the error - Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]

Comment: Can you update your post with the complete _catalina.log_

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
```

[getSessionCookieConfig()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getSessionCookieConfig()) is introduced since version 3, so this error is thrown because there is **abosolutely** an older version in your classpath.

I would suggest to resolve your problem:

1-make sure you update the servlet version to 3

2-try to find any dependecy of servlet-api and get rid of it

3-check your classpath for any potential dependency

4-make that /WEB-INF/lib of course doesn't contain servlet-api

5-make sure that web.xml suits the standards of [servlet 3](https://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have replaced every instance of servlet-api on my PC with version 3 but still getting error. Please note this is happening even when no apps have been added to Tomcat. I literally (1) downloaded Tomcat, (2) unzipped, (3) executed `catalina.bat` and got the error. However, if I add an application to Tomcat via Eclipse, I can successfully launch Tomcat through Eclipse but I still can't run catalina.bat independent of Eclipse. I should also mention `catalina.bat` was working recently. I don't know what has changed.

Comment: see what this shows: System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

Comment: The output of that System.out is `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\bin\tomcat-juli.jar`

Comment: so check if you have any deployed app already, to do that: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat is definitely trying to deploy an application containing the wrong version of `javax.servlet.ServletContext`.

When starting with new fresh tomcat installation please make sure there is no aplication deployed, i.e. that $CATALINA_BASE/webapps is empty and that no $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/[webappname].xml exists. Please make also sure that CATALINA_BASE and CATALINA_HOME environment variables are showing to the right installation. Make sure $CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties is the file from fresh installation. When using the fresh installation together with eclipse then also delete the tmp and work folders afterwards. This is enough to make tomcat start cleanly.

Now to get your tomcat starting **with** your application again. Please make sure the application does not bring the obsolete version of `javax.servlet.ServletContext` with it. Most obviously that would be caused by the application bringing own `servlet-api.jar` but it might also be caused by some other jar containing that class. If you do not find servlet-api in your application then please unpack all jars from your application and look in the `javax.servlet` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check your java lib / all the file system for 'servlet.jar' refer the below thread...

[Java Servlet deployment on tomcat eclipse - Need reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390878/java-servlet-deployment-on-tomcat-eclipse-need-reference)

### given the answer in that thread

Removed servlet.jar in the classpath. I just searched for servlet.jar and removed everything except from lib folder. Which helped me to get rid off this error :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible is that you have the wrong JAR in "lib/ext" in your JAVA_HOME.